# How to get chat message text in HTML/XML format in MS Teams command bot

Tags: teams-toolkit

In Teams command bot, command handler send a commandMessage argument but this contain text as plain text. How I can get html or xml version of this text?

`async handleCommandReceived(  context: TurnContext,  message: CommandMessage,  tokenResponse: TeamsBotSsoPromptTokenResponse  )`

Here CommandMessage.text is plain text. This does not even contain new line character.

I tried TurnContext.Activity.Text but this too contain plain text with escape characters.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The raw message can be accessed via the `Attachments` array on `TurnContext` object.

For example, if a message is sent to the bot with the text `Hello World!`.

You can access the raw message using `context.Attachments[0].content`.

Comment: Image removed, thank you for the heads-up @Rob